# Redirecting to a specific tab on facebook page through facebook app on phone using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, google-chrome

I am trying to open a particular page on facebook with particular tab on the facebook app which gets triggered on a button click

This is my code

```
<button  onclick="myFunction()" class="button small user_review">Review your Trip</button>

function myFunction()
    {
         setTimeout(function () { window.location = "https://www.facebook.com/Savaari/reviews/"; }, 5);
         window.location = "fb://page/300881516665819";

    }
```

I am able to land on the https://www.facebook.com/Savaari/ home page with home tab highlighted through *fb://page/300881516665819*  if the facebook app is installed on phone

I want to land on the reviews tab instead i tried using *fb://page/300881516665819/reviews* but it does not work

Is there another syntax to land on a specific tab through facebook app on phone?

Regards
Sajal

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
<button  onclick="myFunction()" class="button small user_review">Review your Trip</button>


<script>
function myFunction()
    {
         setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com/Savaari/reviews/"; }, 5);
         //window.location.href = "fb://page/300881516665819/reviews";

    }

</script>
```

**UPDATED:**

Newer versions of the FB app does not support `fb://page/`. You should use `fb://facewebmodal/f?href=` instead.

So try doing like this:

```
<button  onclick="myFunction()" class="button small user_review">Review your Trip</button>


    <script>
    function myFunction()
        {
             setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = "fb://facewebmodal/f?href=https://www.facebook.com/Savaari/reviews/"; }, 5);
             //window.location.href = "fb://page/300881516665819/reviews";

        }

    </script>
```

Comment: This opens the page in mobile web browser which is not what i want i want it to be triggered in app that condition is put incase the app is not there on phone so that the link will open in mobile browser

Comment: Please check the Updated version and let me know whether it is working

Comment: Hi I am able to land to the page with ur solution but i have a doubt that i am not able to give review on the page (rate it) Does it give a read only page?